# Importing the views from my app in the project

Tags: django, python-3.x

So im just starting with Django framework and i cannot explain myself why i can't import the views from my app, im watching one course online and im doing the exact same thing but it won't work, anyone help?[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5VhH.png)

Comment: You *can*. You probably have set the project root the wrong way in the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

First of mark the folder as a sources root in pycharm, so you get the correct indexing when trying to import it.

Next up make sure that polls is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`

When developing with python, it's better practice to be explicit rather than implicit, it "might" be better to correct your import to this:
`from polls.view import viewname`

Comment: Thanks a lot, marking the folder as a source folder was the goal